# How can I make a pathless route render correctly inside <Outlet> in React Router Dom 6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

**I built my routes in the new React Router Dom 6 API but the elementError doesn't render correctly inside the `<Outlet>`.** This is important because it is the `RootLayout` of the page that organizes some properties that make the content work.

I've already tried to put the pathless route at the top of the entire hierarchy, putting everyone as its children.

I already tried to remove the `elementError` from the root route, and even so the pathless route does not render in this case.

**The tests I'm doing is if the person tries to enter a route that doesn't exist like `"/about/t"`.**

So I get the `react-router-dom@6` error but I don't get my React element I build. And when I receive it, it is not inside the `Outlet`.

The Site should appear like this.

If the  rendered correctly inside the  component:
[Print of the component changed to manually assume the correct behavior.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMk0d.png)

But the page currently looks like this:
[Where content is not showing in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik3DH.png)

**I can't post pictures directly as this is my first post. So the links are at the end.**

**These are my routes using the new API:**
(Some imports have been removed for readability.)

```
import {
  Route,
  createHashRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createHashRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={<RootLayout />}
      errorElement={<NotFound />}
    >
      <Route errorElement={<NotFound />}>
        <Route index element={<Profile />} />
        <Route
          path="/aboutMe"
          element={<AboutMe />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/contact"
          element={<Contacts />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/projects"
          element={<Projetos />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/infosite"
          element={<SobreOSite />}
        />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
);

export default router;
```

As you can see, it has a parent route that has a pathless route as a child and it has several other children.

If I removed the `errorElement={<NotFound />}` from the root route I don't get my component when giving an error. And the pathless route seems to play no role.

**This is my main:**
Where I use it in the new API route provider.

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

Pretty standard, I'm using Vite.js.

This is my `RootLayout`:
This is where everything that should be rendered by props element and errorElement should appear.

```
import MainNavigation from './MainNavigation';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <>
      <MainNavigation />
      <main className='main-size'>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default RootLayout;
```

And last but not least, this is my error component:

```
import './NotFound.css';

import { Link, useRouteError } from 'react-router-dom';

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import IErrorObject from '../Interfaces/IErrorObject';
import React from 'react';

function ErrorPage() {
  const error: IErrorObject = useRouteError() as IErrorObject;
  console.error('Erro: ', error);

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Não Encontrado - Portifólio</title>
        <meta name='description' content='Não há nada aqui.' />
      </Helmet>
      <Container fluid id="error-page" className='container-nfound bg-light'>
        <h1>Oops!</h1>
        <p>Sorry, an unexpected error has occurred.</p>
        <p>
          <i>{error.statusText || error.message}</i>
        </p>
        <Link to='/'>
          <Button variant='dark'>Vamos para Home!</Button>
        </Link>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default ErrorPage;
```

I don't know if this error component is correct or use is missing something in it that I don't understand.

All these components were basically done following the tutorial from the React Router Dom 6 documentation.

Comment: I don't understand what you think or say is an issue. All the routes rendering content, i.e. have an `element` prop, have a path. What exactly are you doing and what exactly are you expecting the app to do? Can you [edit] to provide clearer details? Can you share the observed vs expected behavior is? Can you include a set of reproduction steps?

Comment: In `react-router-dom` the idiomatic way to handle unknown routes is to render a "catch-all" route, something like `<Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />`. ATM I'm unable to see a way to render both part of the routes, e.g. the `RootLayout` for the navbar, ***and*** the `errorElement` for the 404. It seems that with RRD and raised errors it is one or the other.

Comment: Adding path="*" to the pathless route breaks the application and the site does not render. @DrewReese
I just tried

Comment: I think you misunderstood, `<Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />` is its own "catch-all" ***route***. Render it with the nested routes in lieu of the intermediate layout route specifying only the `errorElement`, which would be removed. The `errorElement` is intended to more of an error boundary, not a "404 page" component.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue after following the React Router 6.8.1 tutorial and this worked for me:

Instead of wrapping the child routes inside of a pathless route, add the catch-all route as a child route itself

```
const router = createHashRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={<RootLayout />}
      errorElement={<NotFound />}
    >
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      
      <Route index element={<Profile />} />
      <Route
        path="/aboutMe"
        element={<AboutMe />}
      />
      <Route
        path="/contact"
        element={<Contacts />}
      />
      <Route
        path="/projects"
        element={<Projetos />}
      />
      <Route
        path="/infosite"
        element={<SobreOSite />}
      />
    </Route>

  )
);
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. It keeps showing a screen outside the <outlet>.

Answer (score 0):

Like chrxtina, I ran into the same issue with my app after following the tutorial. Chrxtina's suggestion didn't fix it for me, but it led me to a solution!

I got it working after adding the `<ErrorElement/>` as a child path, **and** wrapping all the children in a pathless `<ErrorElement/>` as the tutorial says. So it would look like:

```
const router = createHashRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={<RootLayout />}
      errorElement={<NotFound />}
    >
      <Route errorElement={<NotFound />}>
        <Route index element={<Profile />} />
        <Route
          path="/aboutMe"
          element={<AboutMe />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/contact"
          element={<Contacts />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/projects"
          element={<Projetos />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/infosite"
          element={<SobreOSite />}
        />
        <Route 
          path="*" 
          element={<NotFound />} 
        />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
);
```

Hope that helps!